# how to use full Decrypt keys via FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, drm, pyffmpeg

I would like to ask how can I use both DRM keys on FFmpeg to decrypt an MPD , I regulary use second part of key to tun it . , so for example if they keys are :

065c29054f433aa682fd151ab8f0d854:55fb14690af3c5e9ad8ccf869ad588a5 , I use

-decryption_key 55fb14690af3c5e9ad8ccf869ad588a5  -i https://**************.mpd

but seeems some dash require to use full Decrypt key *******************:******************* to be able to run mpd .

how can i put that via using FFmpeg ? as i tried multiple way without success yet .

thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.